# Find closest class onclick

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-10">
   <input type="text" name="postcode" class="postcodeinput" /> 
</div>

<div class="col-md-2">
    <a class="picklocation"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>   
    </a>
</div>
```

When you click on "pickuplocation" I need to get the value of "postcodeinput".

The issue is that there are multiple postcode loop ups on the page so I can't just use `$('.postcodeinput').val()` as there are two and both are handled in the same function.

What I want to do is find the closest element `.postcodeinput` and get the value. I have tried the following jQuery:

```
$('.picklocation').click(function() {
    var postcode = null;
    console.log($(this).prev('.postcodeinput').val());
});
```

I have tried this, however, I am just getting 'undefined'

Answer (score 1):

You need to traverse to `postcodeinput` is child of the sibling element of `picklocation`'s parent element.

```
$('.picklocation').click(function() {
    console.log($(this).parent().prev().find('.postcodeinput').val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i made another solution. now ,after i made the snippet, i realized that it looks like the one Satpal gave ( you can use that one ) . you should use my  solution in case your HTML changes and you want to be more specific about where to look for the value.

**first** look for the parent ( that is a div ) of the button, then search the previous element ( div ) that has a child `.postcodeinput` .

**second** in that div search for the `.postcodeinput` and get it's value

**third** only if that value in not null...do something with it ( in this case write in console )

```js
$('.picklocation').click(function() {
    var postcode = $(this).parent("div").prev("div").has(".postcodeinput")
    var postcodeVal = $(postcode).find('.postcodeinput').val();
    if( postcodeVal != 0) {
    console.log(postcodeVal);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-10">
   <input type="text" name="postcode" class="postcodeinput"  /> 
</div>

<div class="col-md-2">
    <a class="picklocation"><i class="fa fa-search"  aria-hidden="true">First Button</i>   
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-10">
   <input type="text" name="postcode" class="postcodeinput" /> 
</div>

<div class="col-md-2">
    <a class="picklocation"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true">Second Button</i>   
    </a>
</div>
```